# Removing the rings from the Lulav - when?

Tags: minhag, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hoshana-rabbah

I have observed 2 different minhagim when it comes to removing the 3 rings of the lulav on הושענה רבה.

1. To remove it right after the bracha on the lulav, prior to hallel.
2. To wait until after Hallel and remove them one by one over the course of the הקפות.

I am looking for sources discussing these minhagim

Comment: The shulchan aruch says that on hoshana rabba you untie the bundle, i.e. separate the lulav hadasim and aravot. Nothing about rings.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9223&st=&pgnum=250&hilite=